# Creating a simple topology (1 router, 2 switches, 4 hosts) in Mininet

Tags: python, sdn, mininet, ryu

I want to create this simple custom topology in Mininet:

[image: topology here]

s1, s2 ,s3 are 3 OpenVSwitch. h1,h2,h3,h4 are hosts. Blue and red mark bidirectional links. c0 is a controller.

I want to make s1 behave as a SDN router and s2, s3 to behave as SDN switches and c0 being the controller for all of these.

I am trying to run `rest_router.py` and `simple_switch_13.py` scripts from the ryu framework in the controller but I'm unable to do so by typing this command in terminal of controller

```
ryu-manager --app-lists ~/ryu/ryu-master/ryu/app/rest_router.py ~/ryu/ryu-master/ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py
```

Answer (score 1):

ryu does not run mininet,
you will need to run mininet manually

```
sudo mn --topo=tree,depth=2,fanout=2
```

then run the ryu command

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same miniedit.py GUI to export the topology to python script. That will run as `sudo python script.py`